# Extract RSA private key from Cryptico.js then import for browser.subtle

Tags: javascript, cryptography, rsa, cryptico

When i extract RSA private key from Cryptico.js via below code then import for browser.subtle, console tell that:The JWK member "n" could not be base64url decoded or contained padding.

=======added decimalToBase64url(thanks to @Topaco)=======

```
function decimalToBase64url(decimal) {
 
  const hexString = decimal.toString(16);

  
  const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(hexString.match(/.{1,2}/g).map(byte => parseInt(byte, 16)));

 
  const base64 = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uint8Array));


  return base64.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
}


async function convertCrypticoToCryptoKeyPair(crypticoKey) {
  const n = decimalToBase64url(crypticoKey.n);
  console.log(n) // It's b64u!!
  const e = decimalToBase64url(crypticoKey.e);
  const d = decimalToBase64url(crypticoKey.d);
  const p = decimalToBase64url(crypticoKey.p);
  const q = decimalToBase64url(crypticoKey.q);
  const dmp1 = decimalToBase64url(crypticoKey.dmp1);
  const dmq1 = decimalToBase64url(crypticoKey.dmq1);
  const coeff = decimalToBase64url(crypticoKey.coeff);

  const jwkPrivateKey = {
    kty: "RSA",
    n,
    e,
    d,
    p,
    q,
    dmp1,
    dmq1,
    coeff,
  };

  const privateKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "jwk",
    jwkPrivateKey,
    { name: "RSA-PSS", hash: { name: "SHA-256" } },
    true,
    ["sign"]
  );

  const publicKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "jwk",
    { kty: "RSA", n, e },
    { name: "RSA-PSS", hash: { name: "SHA-256" } },
    true,
    ["verify"]
  );

  return { privateKey, publicKey };
}


const PassPhrase = "your_passphrase";
const Bits = 2048;
const crypticoRSAKey = cryptico.generateRSAKey(PassPhrase, Bits);


convertCrypticoToCryptoKeyPair(crypticoRSAKey).then((keyPair) => {
  console.log("Converted CryptoKeyPair:", keyPair);
});
```

below add for Cryptico.js

```
// Export RSA key@furkan-bilgin
    my.exportRSAKey = function(rsaKey) 
    {
        return JSON.stringify(rsaKey);
    }

/*
method 2 Hex @zwisler-a 
function serializeRSAKey(key) {
    return JSON.stringify({
      coeff: key.coeff.toString(16),
      d: key.d.toString(16),
      dmp1: key.dmp1.toString(16),
      dmq1: key.dmq1.toString(16),
      e: key.e.toString(16),
      n: key.n.toString(16),
      p: key.p.toString(16),
      q: key.q.toString(16)
    })
  }
*/
```

kty:
coeff:
d:
dmp1:
dmq1:
e:
n:
p:
q:

how can we let a RSA private key from Cryptico.js import to browser.subtle?

Comment: Neither of your two export functions generates a JWK. Compare the output of these functions with a JWK for RSA, e.g. in [RFC 7517, C.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7517#appendix-C.1): You must adapt the names of the properties and the values must be Base64url encoded (and not hex encoded).

Comment: for method1,  there is jwk.kty = "RSA"; and  it's base64 not hex

Comment: First, `jwk.kty` is not nearly enough to make your data compliant to a JWK for RSA. Second, the data are JavaScript objects that contain the RSA parameters as BigInteger (`exportRSAKey()`) or hex encoded (`serializeRSAKey()`). Edit your question and post output that makes you suspect the parameteres are Base64 (or Base64url) encoded. Also post the code that generates this output. Please provide this in a way that a repro is possible, see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for your remind, just edit my question look more cleanly now

Comment: Your JWK `jwkPrivateKey` contains the RSA parameters as decimal numbers, this is not Base64. Each RSA parameter must be converted to Base64url (Attention: Base64**url** and not Base64). Instead of converting to a decimal number, I would recommend hex encoding with (`toString(16)` instead of `toString()`), then converting the hex encoded string to a *typed array* (`Uint8Array`), then encoding the `Uint8Array` with Base64 and then converting the Base64 encoded string to a Base64url encoded string.

Comment: I have do what you told me to do, but the issue still there, console saying the same The JWK "n" could not be base64url, i update again my question for new code, my brain is burning

Comment: You are close: You have to remove the padding (`=`) in the Base64url encoding and you have to rename `dmp1`, `dmq1` and `coeff` in `jwkPrivateKey` according to the JWK specification. Then it works.